# MS Azure - https support

Tags: azure, dns

New to Azure.  When starting my web app service, it assigns an https:// domain (e.g. website.azurewebsites.net).  However, when buying a custom domain I can only get an http:// domain unless I pay $54/month by scaling my app service plan up to B1?  That seems way unreasonable and it's not clear to me why the original https:// is supported under D1 but not my new domain.  Is this the only route?

Comment: a lot of other features are included into basic SKU. azure is not trying to be a cheapest vds service, web apps offer a lot more than 5$\month vds boxes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in App Service you must be on Basic tier at minimum to assign HTTPS certificates on custom domains.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl#prepare-your-web-app

Comment: Well, you're going to have to send that comment to Microsoft. There are other ways to implement HTTPS though: https://httpsiseasy.com/